# Query with join, group by and count to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

im doing this query on sql and it works, but how do i make it to Linq ?

> select b.Name,a.idempresa,count(1) as cuenta from Descarga_XML_recepcion_V2  as a
> inner join EnterpriseSGE as b on a.idempresa = b.EnterpriseSGEId group by idempresa,b.name

this is what it should bring

```
name1 | 5041 |  583
name2 | 4031 |  1730
name3 | 5042 |  640
name4 | 4034 |  300
name5 | 6047 |  861
name6 | 5043 |  187
name7 | 4033 |  318
```

Comment: please edit your question with what you have tried so far in `c#`

Comment: What do you mean with "it works"? What are you trying to achieve? What data type are you trying to store the data in? When you say "Linq" are you actually referring to entity framework?

Comment: Updated, yes im referring to EF, i need to bring it and show it in a gridview

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight forward translation of the SQL into LINQ yields:

```
var ans = from a in Descarga_XML_recepcion_V2
          join b in EnterpriseSGE on a.idempresa equals b.EnterpriseSGEId
          group 1 by new { a.idempresa, b.name } into ingroup
          select new {
            ingroup.Key.idempresa,
            ingroup.Key.name,
            cuenta = ingroup.Count()
          };
```

Comment: Thanks, this work, just have to wrap into () and add .ToList(), but it works, thank you very much

Comment: @RobertoGonzálezMoreno Yes, I don't instantiate queries in case you want to do something else with them (or use `await`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var results = (from a in Descarga_XML_recepcion_V2
   join b in EnterpriseSGE on a.idempresa equal b.EnterpriseSGEId
   select new { a = a, b = b})
   .GroupBy(x => new { idempresa = x.a.idempresa, name = x.b.name})
   .Select(x => new {name = x.Key.name, idempresa = x.Key.idempressa, count = x.Count()})
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Error on "Key" doesnt exists in the actual context, and on "count=x.Count" says it cannot assign a group of methods

Comment: I updated two hours ago to x.Key

Comment: I updated two hours ago to x.Key.  Count may not need parenthesis .